# How to debug SQLite on VSCODE

Tags: sql, sqlite, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to evaluate a query (see below) on Vscode using SQLite.
It returns an error, which is not quite helpful (see below). I was wondering whether I could have a more insightful debugging? I am not sure how to start debugging to be honest.
Many tks

**Code:**

```
WITH processed_users AS (
    SELECT
        LEFT (u.phone_country, 2) AS short_phone_country,
        u.id
    FROM
        users u
)
SELECT
    t.user_id,
    t.merchant_country,
    Sum (
        t.amount / fx.rate / Power (10, cd.exponent)
    ) AS amount
FROM
    transactions t
    JOIN fx_rates fx ON (
        fx.ccy = t.currency
        AND fx.base_ccy = 'EUR'
    )
    JOIN currency_details cd ON cd.currency = t.currency
    JOIN processed_users pu ON pu.id = t.user_id
WHERE
    t.source = 'GAIA'
    AND pu.short_phone_country = t.merchant_country
GROUP BY
    t.user_id,
    t.merchant_country
ORDER BY
    amount DESC;
```

**Error:**

```
[5:21:43 PM][vscode-sqlite][ERROR] near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: There is no LEFT() function in SQLite. Use SUBSTR().

Comment: Also there is no Power() function.